# Which is better between Ember statement vs HTML statement in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I'm new in Ember.

As I know, the Ember is consist of [.js/.hbs(handlebars)].

when I search the component in the google, I got 2 kinds of source.

1st is like 'HTML'
`<input type="checkbox" class="btn btn-success active" />CheckBox01<br />`

and 2nd is like more 'Ember'.
`{{input type="checkbox" checked=true}}CheckBox02`

but I think these are same.. so I don't select what I use.

Frankly I want to follow 2nd style, but when I try it('https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-toggle'), I got failed.
so I just use 1st style these days. and It is more easy to me because I used to handle HTML.

Anyway, the question is what are the different between Ember Style and HTML Style.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Value binding is the main difference. You can as well do dynamic value binding and since they are handlebars, you get the sophistication of many more helpers.

Please read Ember documentation here, if you have not so.
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/templates/input-helpers/

Thanks

Comment: Thanks your recommend. Is it just difference with how to bind the value? right? As I see that document, I thought it doesn't care what I use between Ember.Input and Input Tag in HTML. Is it ok?

Comment: Ember input helpers are always a good practice. (good it was of some use)